# How to get nesting level of executed function?

Tags: php, recursion, nested, xdebug, multi-level

F.e code snippet

```
function func_1() {
   echo get_nesting_level();
   func_2();
}

function func_2() {
   // how to detect current nesting level? 
   echo get_nesting_level();
   func_1();
}

function get_nesting_level() {
   // how to implement this function?
}


func_1();
```

Expected result
1
2
3
4
...
and so on.
Then I could hit conditional breakpoint if nesting level > 255.
But for the breakpoint I need to know how to detect current nesting level?

This function needs to hit conditionally breakpoint with `XDebug` to understand the issue.
When nesting **level > 255**.

How can I get nesting level of current function on execution flow?

Comment: Use `debug_backtrace()`. It returns an array, and the nesting depth is the array length

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php